# Nash Equilibrium for Game that requires an "action" and a "guess" alternating between two players

Tags: probability, game-theory, expected-value, nash-equilibrium

Hi I'm trying to write an CFR (Counterfactual Regret Minimization) script to calculate the Nash Equilibrium for a popular hand game in Taiwan where you can play with another person. The rules is as follows:

## RULES:

> 1. Two players Rock Paper Scissors to see who goes first.
> 2. Players can either throw one of 3 moves with their **HAND**s:
>
>    - 0 (both fists closed)
>    - 5 (one hand open, one closed)
>    - 10 (both hands open)
> 3. Simultaneously, the active player needs to **GUESS** one of 5 possible counts that are possible from adding the total count of your
>    hand + the opponent's (16 total combos):
>
>    - 0 (both players have their fist closed / 1 combo)
>    - 5 (only one hand open / 4 combos)
>    - 10 (two hands open / 6 combos (2 + 4) )
>    - 15 (three hands open / 4 combos )
>    - 20 (all hands open / 1 combo)
> 4. The player wins the match if the guess is correct. If it's incorrect, the opposing player gets to guess.
> 5. The game continues until there's a winner.

So where I'm confused is based on this rule, starting from the root game node, and your first to act you have actually:

> 3 (NUM_HANDS) * 5 (GUESSES) = 15 Actions branching out of the root. ( 9 if you disqualify invalids)
>
> Actions:
>
> Hand 0 : Guesses: 0, 5, 10, (15), (20)
>
> Hand 5 : Guesses (0), 5, 10, 15, (20)
>
> Hand 10 : Guesses (0), (5), 10, 15, 20

Where as for the opponent who's defending, there is only 3 possible actions:

> Actions:
>
> Hand 0, Hand 5, Hand 10

So they players actually take turns between selecting 15 actions or 3 actions. My question is how do you set things up to calculate the  cumulative regret for the active player (hero) and the defending player (villain) for each rounds?

Do you need two sets of probability matrix to represent hero / villain ? If so how to arrive at a general strategy? Or is the only way is to have two sets of strategy for each situation?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is way more complicated than necessary. The guessing player is effectively merely guessing how many hands the other player will open; it doesn’t make a difference how many hands the guessing player opens, since she knows that and can just add it to her guess.

Thus, both players effectively have three pure strategies, and these are fully symmetric, so the Nash equilibrium is that they both choose each strategy with probability $\frac13$. That is, the non-guessing player opens $0$, $1$ or $2$ hands, each with probability $\frac13$, and the guessing player guesses $0$, $1$ or $2$ hands, each with probability $\frac13$, and opens an arbitrary number of hands and adds that to the guess.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. I haven't thought of it that way, which is really insightful. Let's say for the purpose of the code I'm writing I want to calculate the % of each Hand / Guess combo after many iterations for exploitation, such that if I'm given a particular strategy for player 2, where P_2(a) stands for the probability of player2 taking that action. P_2(0) = 1/4, P_2(1) = 1/2, P_2(2) = 1/4 and P_1(a) is 1/3 for all actions initially. How would I formulate the utility eq to get P_1(a) for all actions as it converges to equilibrium and to output all the Hand / Guess combos that happened?

Comment: @alchuang: I'm afraid I don't understand what you're trying to do. Apparently player $2$ is not playing the strategy from the Nash equilibrium strategy profile. Then what "converges to equilibrium"? If from past experience player $2$ is expected to play the strategy you describe, then player $1$ should guess $1$ hand; this is the best response to that strategy, but it has nothing to do with equilibrium. I'm sorry, I may just be misunderstanding what you wrote.

Comment: Sorry, what i meant is given P_2( 0.25, 0.5, 0.25) for 0,1,2 hands, what I'm trying to find is the strategy to maximize winning for P1. The code starts with P_1( 0.33, 0.33, 0.33 ) and after running multiple iterations of Counterfactual Regret Minimization (http://modelai.gettysburg.edu/2013/cfr/cfr.pdf) it would slowly converge to best winning strategy. I'll modify above comment to clarify as its not equilibrium i'm looking for but the actually the a best response to opponent strategy

Comment: Also- what I mean by hand / guess combos is that for each correct guess of the opponent hand there's actually 3 combos. Let's call P_1(g) the probability of p1 guessing P2 action. So probability of each unique hand / guess combo would be P_1(g) * 1/3, as the occurrences are distributed equally because P1 can open arbitrary number based on guess?

Comment: @alchuang: First, about the best response to the strategy $(0.25,0.5,0.25)$: The best response is to guess one hand, since the winning probability is the probability with which player $2$ chooses our guess, and that's maximal at $0.5$ for $1$ hand. About the hand/guess combo: no, there's no need to make the guessing player's open hands equiprobable. The guessing player can open an arbitrary number of hands (and add it to the guess), since this has no influence on the winning probability.

Comment: @alchuang: The entire aspect of the guessing player opening hands is just a distraction. You can take it out of the game without changing the game. If you want to leave it in the game, any probability distribution over the guessing player's open hands yields the same expected return, so a Nash equilibrium can have any such distribution, not necessarily a uniform one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107432/discussion-between-alchuang-and-joriki).